# Meteor allow users to extend application

Tags: meta-programming, upload

I'm trying to make a meteor app which every user can extend. Meteor uses hot code swapping which I would like to use, so I'd probably need to save scripts on file system of the server.

Have You got any ideas to store and execute user-made scripts in file-system in both easy for the user and secure way?

Comment: You want to ensure that code run on the server is safe to run?  That's no small feat.  There's so much you could overlook that it is hardly worth trying.  If it is client-side code, then that is doable so long as you make sure that the server can never run it by mistake.